# Nicely delegate housekeeping code to the Superclass?

Tags: inheritance, kotlin

I have two classes:

**CanvasElement**

```
abstract class CanvasElement(
    var posX: Double = 0.0,
    var posY: Double = 0.0,
    var fillStyle: String = "",
    var strokeStyle: String = "",
    var shadowColor: String = "",
    var shadowBlur: String = "",
    var shadowOffsetX: Double = 0.0,
    var shadowOffsetY: Double = 0.0,
    var context: CanvasRenderingContext2D? = null) {

constructor(posX: Double, posY: Double) : this() {
    this.posX = posX
    this.posY = posY
}

fun registerWithContext() {
    this.context = this.context
}

fun move(onXaxis: Double, onYaxis: Double) {
    this.posX = posX + onXaxis
    this.posY = posY + onYaxis
}


fun drawOnCanvasContext(drawFunctionOfElement: Unit) {
    this.context?.beginPath();
}

fun prepareContext() {
    this.context?.beginPath();
}

fun finishDrawingOn() {
    this.context?.fillStyle = this.fillStyle
    this.context?.strokeStyle = this.strokeStyle
    this.context?.shadowColor = shadowColor
    this.context?.save()
    this.context?.stroke()
    this.context?.fill()
}

fun setFillStyle(fillStyle: String) {

}

abstract fun drawOnContext()
}
```

**Circle**

```
class Circle(var radius : Double = 0.0,
        posX : Double,
        posY : Double,
        fillStyle : String,
        strokeStyle : String,
        shadowColor : String,
        shadowBlur : String,
        shadowOffsetX : Double,
        shadowOffsetY : Double,
        context : CanvasRenderingContext2D) : CanvasElement(posX = posX, posY = posY, fillStyle = fillStyle, strokeStyle = strokeStyle, shadowColor = shadowColor, shadowOffsetX = shadowOffsetX, shadowOffsetY = shadowOffsetY, context = context ){

constructor(posX: Double,
            posY: Double,
            radius: Double,
            strokeStyle: String,
            fillStyle: String,
            context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) : this(posX = posX, posY = posY, radius = radius, fillStyle = fillStyle, strokeStyle = strokeStyle, shadowColor = "", shadowBlur = "", shadowOffsetX = 0.0, shadowOffsetY = 0.0, context = context)

override fun drawOnContext(){
    prepareContext()
    context?.arc(posX, this.posY, this.radius,0.0,2 * kotlin.math.PI)
    finishDrawingOn()
}
}
```

As you can see, Circle overwrites the abstract fun `drawOnContext()`
(There are other subclasses of CanvasElement like Rectangle, etc.) which differ in the `context?...` call inside of `drawOnContext()`

**PROBLEM:**
But at the moment, every new subclass of CanvasElement has to call the housekeeping functions `prepareContext()` and `finishDrawingOn()` and it is easy to forget to implement this. I Want to get rid of that redundancy.

How can I delegate these implementation to the superclass?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is context nullable? It's causing you to have to put ?s all over the place.

Comment: Because I wanted an exception if anything goes wrong. If I do not make it nullable I have to initialize it with a dummy `CanvasRenderingContext2D` which is not the one I need for drawing on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CanvasElement, replace

```
abstract fun drawOnContext()
}
```

with

```
fun drawOnContext()
    prepareContext()
    onDraw()
    finishDrawingOn()
}

abstract protected fun onDraw()
```

Then in your subclasses:

```
override protected fun onDraw(){
    context?.arc(posX, this.posY, this.radius,0.0,2 * kotlin.math.PI)
}
```

Although, I'd probably simplify it by eliminating the redundant functions and many of the null-safe calls:

```
fun drawOnContext()
    context?.apply{
        beginPath()
        onDraw(this)
        fillStyle = this@CanvasElement.fillStyle
        strokeStyle = this@CanvasElement.strokeStyle
        shadowColor = this@CanvasElement.shadowColor
        save()
        stroke()
        fill()
    }
}

abstract protected fun onDraw(context: Context)
```